# Problema com annotation após atualizar android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, annotation

eu possuo uma implementação feita com Socket.IO no android. Porém após eu atualizar o android studio, parou de funcionar tudo...

Eu criei umas rotinas para facilitar a implementação da lib, uma delas é uma annotation `@IOXEvent`.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IOXEvent {
    String value();
}
```

Para fazer o uso dessa annotation, eu informava o nome do evento que eu gostaria de ouvir na classe, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
IOXEvent("mensagem:nova")
public void aoReceberMensagem(String mensagem) {
      Log.i("TESTE", mensagem)
}
```

Acontece que a classe `aoReceberMensagem` não é utilizada pelo código do meu app, então ela fica cinza como se não houvesse referência para ela. Então ao utilizar a rotina abaixo, o nome do método vem como "wait" e a variável `ann` vem como `null`.

```
public void attach(final Object o) {
        Class c = o.getClass();
        for (final Method m : c.getMethods()) {
            IOXEvent ann = m.getAnnotation(IOXEvent.class);
            if(ann != null && !ann.value().equals("")) {
                this.sdd.off(ann.value());
                this.on(ann.value(), new IOXListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        try {
                            m.invoke(o, args);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Log.e("IOX_ERROR", ex.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Acredito que de alguma forma os métodos não utilizados estão sendo removidos na compilação do app mesmo em debug. Alguém sabe como eu posso resolver isso?

Comment: eu acho que os metodos que nao sao usados(chamados) na aplicacao nao funcionam

Comment: Então @GabrielAguiar mas antes funcionava... O problema passou a ocorrer depois deu atualizar o Android Studio. Ele é chamado via reflection, baseado na string da annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema não estava na atualização do Android Studio mas sim no proguard.

Recentemente foi adicionado o proguard no projeto e não foram realizados testes com o chat.

Para resolver o problema eu adicionei a linha abaixo no arquivo `proguard-rules.pro` da aplicação:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.minhaaplicacao.moon.iox.IOXEvent *;
}
```